# VS code wont start debian Xfce

Tags: visual-studio-code, debian-jessie

Just installed VS Code on my debian machine on AWS services. 
I installed it trough the steps on this page: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

But when i type "code" in the terminal nothings happens. Not even a error message.
 Also when i start it trough the GUI, simple nothings happens. Sometimes i see code for a second in the taks manager but thats it.

i would really appreciate any help to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I finally made VS code working on AWS linux instance...
Here is my environment
1. EC2 instance: t2.medium (t2.nano was not good enough power for VS code)
  - t2.small was manageable, too.
2. GUI : ubuntu mate core
  - personally, this looks better than Xfce.
3. Tweaked linuxxcb.so: I strongly recommend you to try this tweak first in your environment
  - sudo sed -i 's/BIG-REQUESTS/_IG-REQUESTS/' /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0

You can get more details from [here](https://github.com/hochae/AWS).